# TypeError: QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsPolygon'

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

According to documentation: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGeometry.html?highlight=frompolygonxy#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY

> fromPolygonXY(polygon: object)→ QgsGeometry¶ Creates a new geometry
> from a QgsPolygon
>
> Parameters polygon (object) –
>
> Return type QgsGeometry

But on executing the following code, when i try to give out a `QgsPolygon` object as an argument to `QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY` it throws out an error

```
def create_circle(x, y, r):
    layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:4326', 'poly' , "memory")
    pr = layer.dataProvider() 

    pt = QgsFeature()
    point = QgsPoint(x,y)
    # pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point))
    pr.addFeatures([pt])

    layer.updateExtents()

    circle = qgis.core.QgsCircle.fromCenterDiameter(center = point, diameter = 2*r)
    feat = QgsFeature()
    # print(dir(QgsGeometry))
    print(dir(circle))
    print(circle.toPolygon())
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY(circle.toPolygon()))
    
    # circle_geom = QgsGeometry.makeCircle(point, r)
    pr.addFeatures([feat])
    return layer
```

`circle.toPolygon()` returns a `QgsPolygon` object as `QgsCircle` class has `QgsEllipse` as the base class

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsEllipse.html?highlight=topolygon#qgis.core.QgsEllipse.toPolygon

> toPolygon(self, segments: int = 36)→ QgsPolygon¶ Returns a segmented
> polygon.
>
> Parameters segments (int = 36) – Number of segments used to segment
> geometry.
>
> Return type QgsPolygon

qgis details:

```
QGIS version
3.21.0-Master
QGIS code revision
1906e19899
Qt version
5.15.2
Python version
3.8.7
GDAL/OGR version
3.2.3
PROJ version
6.3.2
EPSG Registry database version
v9.8.6 (2020-01-22)
GEOS version
3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
SQLite version
3.31.1
PDAL version
2.2.0
PostgreSQL client version
12.3
SpatiaLite version
4.3.0a
QWT version
6.1.4
QScintilla2 version
2.11.4
OS version
macOS 11.1
```

Comment: @MrXsquared I get `NameError: name 'QgsPolygonXY' is not defined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out, from other parts of the documentation the correct arguments that should be provided to `fromPolygonXY` is a `[[QgsPointsXY_obj1, QgsPointsXY_obj2, ...]]`

link: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html?highlight=polygonxy#geometry-construction

and the documentation at https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGeometry.html?highlight=frompolygonxy#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY seems to be incorrect.

I also raised a Bug Report: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/45099

I fixed it in the code with a little bit of rearrangements as:

```
def create_circle(x, y, r):
    layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:4326', 'poly' , "memory")
    pr = layer.dataProvider() 

    pt = QgsFeature()
    point = QgsPoint(x,y)
    pr.addFeatures([pt])

    layer.updateExtents()

    circle = qgis.core.QgsCircle.fromCenterDiameter(center = point, diameter = 2*r)
    feat = QgsFeature()
    circle_points_qgspoint_xy = []
    for i in circle.points():
        circle_points_qgspoint_xy.append(QgsPointXY(i))
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([circle_points_qgspoint_xy]))
    
    pr.addFeatures([feat])

    # add layer to the registry
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    # set extent to the extent of our layer
    canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())

    # set the map canvas layer set
    canvas.setLayers([layer])

create_circle(0.662, 0.1822, 0.25)
```

Comment: Python list comprehension: `circle_points_qgspoint_xy = [QgsPointXY(i) for i in circle.points()]`